# Bad input shape error on SVM training using scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I m a little new to scikit and ML. I m trying to train an SVM classifier for one vs all classification. I m using the following code.

```
g=list()
for i in range(0,120):
    g.append(1)
for i in range(120,240):
    g.append(2)

u=set(g)
numclasses=len(u)

lin_clf = svm.LinearSVC()
lin_clf.fit(features,u)
```

Features is a 72900*120 array. I m getting features from a different python code and calling that here. It throws the following warning and error.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py:279: 
DeprecationWarning: fromstring() is deprecated. Please call frombytes() instead.
image = Image.fromstring(mode, shape, strdata)
```

error

```
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

Please comment if you need the code for feature extraction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Which line of the code is throwing the error? Is it `lin_clf.fit(features,u)`?

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) of LinearSVC, the arguments for `fit(X,y)` are

> X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>
> Training vector, where n_samples in the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.
>
> y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
>
> Target vector relative to X

However, the `u` in your code is a python `set`. It should be a numpy array of length 72900.